# When to close Sqlite database

Tags: android, database, multithreading, sqlite

I have some listviews in every activity in my app. For every getView(), I create a thread to open a Sqlite database and close it after(in each thread). But, I got database locked error.

**Note: The app can have like 6 threads running at the same time using each there own SQLiteOpenHelper**

So when Android said to close the database when not needed, is he talking about closing when the app is in background or for every request using transaction or not?

Code:

```
public class TemporarySqliteDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

  public TemporarySqliteDB(Context context) {
    super(context, "Temporary", null, 1);
  }
  //..........
}

public class DaoImage{
  private SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase;

  public DaoImage(Context ctx) {
    writableDatabase = new TemporarySqliteDB(ctx).getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void close() {
    writableDatabase.close();
  }
 }
```

In my thread run()

```
//this give locked error while instanciating
DaoImage daoImage = null;
            try {
                daoImage = new DaoImage(ctx.get());

                //.....
            }finally {
                if(daoImage != null)
                    daoImage.close();
            }

//This without error
DaoImage daoImage = new DaoImage(ctx.get());
//....
```

**Without closing the database I see the memory use is ok. But I don't know if it's best practice to leave the database open.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Android's SQLite thread-safety you need to be using the same instance of your `SQliteOpenHelper` class. Once you do that, closing databases after every use like you're doing is correct, and `SQliteOpenHelper` takes care of concurrency.

An example via making your helper a singleton:

```
public class TemporarySqliteDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static TemporarySqliteDB instance;

  @synchronized public static getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new TemporarySqliteDB(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return instance;
  }

  // rest of class here
}
```

Then later something like

```
SQLiteDatabase db = TemporarySqliteDB.getInstance().getWriteableDatabase();
try {
  // use db
} finally {
  db.close();
}
```

What's happening with your current usage pattern is that instead of gainine `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s thread safety you're using SQLite's concurrency safe guards on the sqlite file itself, which try to prevent corrupting the database with concurrent access which could be from separate processes.

Comment: It's great. that's what I was looking for. But using the singleton pattern allow you to close and open the DB once because, trying to open the DB when already closed give that exception: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:**